# Is Ubuntu required for installing Lubuntu

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu

Do you need to install Ubuntu before you install Lubuntu?  I am getting errors on my Lubuntu install and wondered if that might be the problem.

Comment: No. Ubuntu and Lubuntu are basically the same with a different desktop. The installation procedure is exactly the same. If you're "getting errors" then logic and common sense tell us that those errors should have been mentioned. Please [edit] accordingly but, if installing in a modern machine, first read this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Please tell/show us the errors. What is your configuration? How much RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lubuntu is another Linux distro which is based on Ubuntu. Therefore, installing Lubuntu alone would be sufficient. The errors you are facing might be due to some issues with the partitioning or the installation.

It is also a good practice to compare the SHA256SUM of the ISO you downloaded with the SHA256SUM that is provided in the Lubuntu website. To check a SHA256SUM, go to the folder the ISO, open the terminal and type:

```
sha256sum name-of-the-iso-file
```

That would ensure that the ISO that you have downloaded is exactly the same that is provided by the developers. The errors might also happen if you have installed the OS using a corrupted ISO.

Answer (score 0):

No.You Don't need to Install Ubuntu before Installing Lubuntu.

Technically Lubuntu = Ubuntu i.e Lubuntu is Ubuntu.

Lubuntu just have different Desktop-Environment That is LXDE.